# How can multiple null terminated strings be handled in a DLL-function result?

Tags: interoperability, .netlink

I am trying to connect a classic System Dynamics tool (Vensim DSS) with Mathematica using a DLL that is included in Vensim DSS. Reading though [the instructions on how to define DLL functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/tutorial/CallingNETFromMathematica.html#32076) on how to declare arguments - here strings - I found that if there are [out] strings one should use the .NET class *System.Text.StringBuilder*.

So applying the advice given will look like this:

```
(* definitions *)
$maxBufLen = 1000;
strOutput = NETNew["System.Text.StringBuilder", $maxBufLen];
vensimGetInfo = DefineDLLFunction["vensim_get_info", vensimDLL,
"int", {"int", "System.Text.StringBuilder", "int"}];

(* usage *)
infoWanted = 3; bufLen = $maxBufLen;
vensimGetInfo[infoWanted, strOutput, bufLen];
strOuput@ToString[]
```

Unfortunately this only works properly for a single string and some information will be returned by the DLL function as a series of null terminated strings that is finally ended by a double null. In such a case the above procedure will only return the first string omitting the rest.

What can be done?

Comment: IMO, this is really a Windows/.Net question rather than a *Mathematica* issue *per se*. Relevant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx, http://snipplr.com/view/27336/. The answer would seem to be that `System.Text.StringBuilder` does not support this type of string and something else should be used instead. I personally have no experience with .Net, so I will let someone else make the suggestion as to what that should be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, I should mention that Vensim also has a Java interface that you could call using J/Link. The Java signature of this particular function is

```java
static String[] get_info(int infowanted);
```

so you can see that the different strings are conveniently returned in an array for you.

But you can also do what you want using .NET/Link's `DefineDLLFunction`. You have to drop down to low-level memory allocations. Declare the buffer that will be filled with the strings as an `IntPtr`:

```
vensimGetInfo = DefineDLLFunction["vensim_get_info", vensimDLL, "int", {"int", "IntPtr", "int"}];
```

Then allocate a buffer of a size large enough to hold all the data:

```
LoadNETType["System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal"];
buf = Marshal`AllocHGlobal[$maxBufLen];
```

Call the DLL function:

```
infoWanted = 3;
numBytes = vensimGetInfo[infoWanted, buf, $maxBufLen];
```

One way to get the data from `buf` is to copy it into a .NET array, and then use `NETObjectToExpression` to convert it into a list of character values.

```
managedArray = NETNew["System.Byte[]", numBytes];
Marshal`Copy[buf, managedArray, 0, numBytes];
bytes = NETObjectToExpression[managedArray]
```

bytes will look something like `{100, 105, ..., 0, 97, 100, ..., 0, 105, 102, ... 0, 0}`. Use whatever method you like to convert these character values into separate strings, such as

```
FromCharacterCode[DeleteCases[SplitBy[bytes, # != 0 &], {0..}]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Todd, that pretty much looks like THE answer to the problem. For completeness I will also point out a solution using the DLL function "vensim_get_substring" which Ventana posted on the Vensim Forum: http://www.vensim.com/documentation/index.html?26210.htm